# GIT public branch cleanup into new branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

I have to cleanup a remote/public branch "OLD" because it contain some bad/huge commits.

**OLD - simplified graph**

```
(...) -> c234 -> c235(huge to fix) -> c236 -> c237(huge to fix) -> c238 -> c239 -> (...) -> HEAD
```

**To do so I did:**

1) I created a "NEW" branch.

2) Get back before first huge commit (c234)

3) Cherry pick all commits before last huge commit. (c236)

4) Then I copied all changed files from "OLD" branch after last huge commit (c237)

5) And finally created many small commits reflecting changes (c235, c237)

**NEW now - simplified graph**

```
(...) -> c234 -> c236 -> (many commits reflecting state after c237) -> HEAD
```

Now in my opinion I have to rebase/cherry-pick all changes made after (c237) on "OLD" into top of the "NEW"

**NEW expected - simplified graph**

```
(...) -> c234 -> c236 -> (many commits reflecting state after c237) -> c238 -> c239 -> (...) -> HEAD
```

I tried before this git-rebase -i but because this was a public repo, it contain many (there is almost 400 commits to HEAD of OLD) merges and from time to time I had to resolve conflicts - witch can take me many days.

Any ideas howto do deal with it.

Comment: What is the **exact** rebase command you used?

Comment: First try was
git-rebase -i --onto refs/heads/old c235

The idea was to change commits order, join them, split them into many small.

But any time when user had a merge conflict - I have to resolve it once again, I give up after 20 manual merges.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `(many commits reflecting state after c237)` does not really reproduce the same state in the end as you had in your `OLD` branch at commit `c237`. If you did, you shouldn't get **any** merge conflicts.

This means you need to do a `git diff c237` before attempting the rebase in order to see what you missed.

Comment: I tried also do a rebase without any edit, but it asked me to resolve conflicts (probably because many commits were made outside OLD branch and there were originally merged)